# How to color point in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Hey I know that if I want to color specific point, I can do it using the `fillColor` attribute of current marker.

But When I hover the point, the color return to be the default color of the graph,how can I prevent such effect?

I want the point to be red in both situation(onhover event and not onhover event),

what attribute per point do I need to change for this effect to happen?

I have added a demo below, the demo act like this: when you click the canvas of the graph,a new graph is being generated and the first point is red but when I hover it , it return to its default color.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            margin: [70, 50, 60, 80],
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                    // find the clicked values and the series
                    var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
                        y = e.yAxis[0].value,
                        series = this.series[0];
          var chart = this;
                    this.addSeries({
                   data: [{ x:x, y:y, marker:{radius: 5 , fillColor: "red" }},{x:(x*2), y:(y*2)}]
               })
         

                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'User supplied data'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the plot area to add a point. Click a point to remove it.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        'click': function () {
                            if (this.series.data.length > 1) {
                                this.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[20, 20], [80, 80]]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in states option where you are setting the marker fillColor:

```
marker: {
    radius: 5, 
    fillColor: 'red', 
    states: {
        hover: {
            fillColor: 'red',
            }
        } 
    }
```